# How to build a local COM Server and Client?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, com

To build local COM exe server:

I have referred the implementation from below [link](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/8679/Building-a-LOCAL-COM-Server-and-Client-A-Step-by-S).

**Problems:**

1. It has not been explained how to register these server.
2. There is no implementation of proxy and stub.Is it required to implement? or internally built in COM library?

Comment: The codeproject article contains a registry file which you're supposed to use for registration. Did this not work for you? Why not ask the original author this question? CodeProject does have a "comments and discussions" section at the bottom of each article.

Comment: It gave me error class not registered. I could not find the clsid in registry editor

Comment: How to add proxy and stub to send back response to the client from the server